# iterate sort within groupby

Tags: python, sorting, group-by, pandas

I would like to sort this Series within each level of col_0

```
import pandas as pd
a = 'a b b a a a a b b'.split()
b = 'b a b b b a a b b'.split()
aS = pd.Series(a)
bS = pd.Series(b)
ctab = pd.crosstab(aS,bS).unstack()

In[2]: ctab

Out[2]:
col_0  row_0
a      a        2
       b        1
b      a        3
       b        3
dtype: int64
```

So I get something like

```
col_0  row_0
a      b        1
       a        2
b      a        3
       b        3
dtype: int64
```

I tried

```
ctab.groupby(level=0).sort(ascending=False)
```

but I got a cryptic error message.

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: @mtitan8 `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ctab.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(pd.Series.sort_index, ascending=False)
```

or:

```
ctab.sort_index(ascending=[True, False])
```